# JS: Extract number from string, that is before a specific word

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to extract the number that is exactly before the text `kcal`. How may I do this?

```
foo = "1119 kJ / 266 kcal";

// want to return: 266
```

http://regex101.com/r/tZ3fH8/1

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/tZ3fH8/2 and for js (because you choose regexp for php in your link) - http://regex101.com/r/tZ3fH8/3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) group to match and capture the digits preceding that word. The below regex will match/capture any character of: digits, `.` "one or more" times preceded by optional whitespace followed by the word "kcal".

```
var r = '1119 kJ / 266 kcal'.match(/([\d.]+) *kcal/)[1];
if (r)
    console.log(r); //=> "266"
```

Comment: Include dot into the capture group.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is simpler and cleaner but if it's not for you then here's another route. You can split your string by the "/" then split it again by the resulting pairs:

```
foo = "1119 kJ / 266 kcal";

pairs = foo.split("/");
res = pairs[1]; //get second pair

var res = foo.split(" "); //spit pair by space.

if (isNumber(res[0]) {
    alert("It's a number!");
}

function isNumber(n) {
    //must test for both conditions 
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```